# ssh bash completion file

Tags: bash, autocomplete

for git I use this bash completion file
http://repo.or.cz/w/git.git/blob_plain/HEAD:/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash

you know a good bash ssh completion file?
// or other goods bash completion files ?

Comment: ähm what exaclty is your question, what do you mean by completion? am i assuming correctly that you want so synchronize files over ssh?

Comment: no, a bash completion file, is file with bash functions for automcompletation the arguments with TAB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*The* [bash-completion](http://bash-completion.alioth.debian.org/) package is the one to start with. If it's not already on your system, it should be available through the package manager for your distribution. It comes with a file for ssh completions along with many others.